# Python - merging 3 data frames and creating an output

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very tricky question, i tried all the solutions i have so i hope someone can give me any kind of help.

I have the following:
***df1(old database):***

| Product | ID | Risk | Damage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wheel 1 | 123 | Negligible | High |
| wheel 2 | 453 | High | Low |

***df2(new database):***

| ID | Risk | Damage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | High | Low |
| 453 | High | Law |

***Output:***

| ID | Risk old (df1) | Risk new (df2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Negligible | High |
| 453 | High | High |

***The tricky part:***
This is just an example but in reality i have  lots of columns like the risk and damage so i have to create this report time to time for different columns .So i was thinking to add a df3 with only one row with the required column to be analyzed. And then to kind of having the code to look for that particular column based on df3(if you have any other ideas on how i should do this, please let me know).

Thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciated!

Comment: Which library is used for the dataframes (pandas, polars, spark,...)? Add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Pandas, appologies

Answer (score 0):

Select the required column along with ID column then merge on `ID` and specify the suffixes to differentiate between new/old columns

```
c = ['ID', 'Risk']
df2[c].merge(df1[c], on='ID', how='left', suffixes=['_new', '_old'])
```

---

```
    ID Risk_new    Risk_old
0  123     High  Negligible
1  453     High        High
```